# Button not Triggering Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about how to see the responses in the following code when the button is pressed.

Firstly, let me say I'm new to Javascript and in between waiting on a reply from my professor.  I've researched w3schools, breaking down a few different keywords and elements in the Javascript using the w3schools keyword search bar and came up short as to the specific question I have.  I also uploaded to w3c validator.org and didn't see much to interpret.  I then tried using the inspection option in my web browser.  I found 18 errors there, but didn't really understand them either.  Viewing the code was attempted in 5 different browsers and nothing happens when the button is pressed.  Any ideas?  My guess is it is some type of syntax area, but I don't yet know what I'm looking for.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

```js
function collectInput() {
          var textbox1 = 
       document.getElementById('textbox'1);
                // compare the value in the textbox to an empty   string
                if(textbox1.value == "") {
                        // if true, send the error message to the display point
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML
            = "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";    
                };
        };

function collectInput() {
         var textbox1 =
     document.getElementById('textbox1');
        if(textbox1.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML
     = "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";
        } else { 
            
     document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You
     entered: "+ textbox1.value;            
           };
      };
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header><h1>Header</h1></header> 
      <section><h1>Section</h1>
    
        <input type="text" id="textbox1">
        <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Send to the    Script!" onclick="collectInput()">

        <p id="response"></p><!-- the display point, the place to send the response message  -->
    
      </section>    
  </div>    
</body>
<footer>
  <p class="copy">Copyright (c) 2014 All Rights Reserved</p>    
</footer>
```

Comment: when you have two functions with the same name, the last one loaded replaces the previous one so the first one is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly why there are two script with same function `collectInput` remove  one secondly there is an syntax error which has been resolved in below snippet take a look at it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>| HTML5 CSS |</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <!-- There was two pieces to the instructions.  The second is below, but I'm unsure as to whether the funtion requires a second script or not.  Both returned negative attempts.  The instructions are supposed to create a page that shows one response or the other.  -->  
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function collectInput() {
         var textbox1 =
     document.getElementById('textbox1');
        if(textbox1.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML
     = "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";
        } else { 
            
     document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You entered: "+ textbox1.value;            
           }
      }   
     </script>    
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header><h1>Header</h1></header> 
      <section><h1>Section</h1>
    
        <input type="text" id="textbox1">
        <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Send to the    Script!" onclick="collectInput()">

        <p id="response"></p><!-- the display point, the place to send the response message  -->
    
      </section>    
  </div>    
</body>
<footer>
  <p class="copy">Copyright (c) 2014 All Rights Reserved</p>    
</footer>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code had few errors but after editing it works fine.

The first error was calling the same function `collectInput()` twice.

The second error is the `id` name should be inside single quotes not the way you have written

```
document.getElementById('textbox'1);
```

It should be

```
document.getElementById('textbox1');
```

Another error was breaking line for a single statement

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You
     entered: "+ textbox1.value;
```

It should be

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You entered: "+ textbox1.value;
```

Below is the correct code. Hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>| HTML5 CSS |</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
 <!-- There was two pieces to the instructions.  The second is below, but I'm unsure as to whether the funtion requires a second script or not.  Both returned negative attempts.  The instructions are supposed to create a page that shows one response or the other.  -->  
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function collectInput() {
         var textbox1 =
     document.getElementById('textbox1');
        if(textbox1.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML
     = "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";
        } if(textbox1.value != "") { 
            
     document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You entered: "+ textbox1.value;            
           }
      }   
     </script>    
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header><h1>Header</h1></header> 
      <section><h1>Section</h1>
    
        <input type="text" id="textbox1">
        <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Send to the    Script!" onclick="collectInput()">

        <p id="response"></p><!-- the display point, the place to send the response message  -->
    
      </section>    
  </div>    
</body>
<footer>
  <p class="copy">Copyright (c) 2014 All Rights Reserved</p>    
</footer>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HERE IS THE WORKING CODE:**

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>`<BR>
`<html>`<BR>
 `<head>`<BR>
    `<title>| HTML5 CSS |</title> `<BR>
    `<meta charset="UTF-8">`<BR>
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`<BR>
    `<script type="text/javascript">`<BR>
     `  function collectInput() {`<BR>
      `    var textbox1 =document.getElementById('textbox1');`<BR>
      `          // compare the value in the textbox to an empty   string`<BR>
       `         if(textbox1.value == "") {`<BR>
        `                // if true, send the error message to the display point`<BR>
 `               document.getElementById('response').innerHTML= "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";`<BR>
          `      }`<BR>
        `}`<BR>
      `</script>   `<BR>
` <!-- There was two pieces to the instructions.  The second is below, but I'm unsure as to whether the funtion requires a second script or not.  Both returned negative attempts.  The instructions are supposed to create a page that shows one response or the other.  -->`  <BR>
`     <script type="text/javascript">`<BR>
 `       function collectInput() {`<BR>
  `       var textbox1 =`<BR>
   `  document.getElementById('textbox1');`<BR>
    `    if(textbox1.value == "") {`<BR>
     `   document.getElementById('response').innerHTML= "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";`
      `  } else {` <BR>
             `document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You entered: "+ textbox1.value;`<BR>            
      `  }`<BR>
     ` } `<BR>
     `</script>`  <BR>  
   `</head>`<BR>
`<body>`<BR>
 ` <div class="wrapper">`<BR>
  `  <header><h1>Header</h1></header>` <BR>
      `<section><h1>Section</h1>`<BR>
            `<input type="text" id="textbox1">`<BR>
        `<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Send to the    Script!" onclick="collectInput()">`<BR>

  `      <p id="response"></p><!-- the display point, the place to send the response message  -->`<BR>

   `   </section>`  <BR>  
  `</div>`  <BR>  
`</body>`<BR>
`<footer>`<BR>
 ` <p class="copy">Copyright (c) 2014 All Rights Reserved</p>    `<BR>
`</footer>`    <BR>
`</html>`<BR>
```

Comment: please explain what you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you so much for getting back to me.  It was funny that I didn't know what the response would be when I submitted the thread because the Posting Section said something to the extent that made me think there's a chance my question may not get answered.  So, hopefully, I can ask many questions and gain much knowledge over the years with my coding journey.  Below is the code that was derived from all of your responses.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>| HTML5 CSS |</title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function collectInput() {
    var textbox1 = 
document.getElementById('textbox1');
                // compare the value in the textbox to an empty string
                if(textbox1.value == "") {
                        // if true, send the error message to the display point
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML
            = "Hey, you didn't put anything in the box!?!";    
                } else { 
            
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "You entered: "+ textbox1.value; 
        }
}
</script>   
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header><h1>Header</h1></header> 
<section><h1>Section</h1>
    
<input type="text" id="textbox1">
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Send to the Script!" onclick="collectInput()">

<p id="response"></p><!-- the display point, the place to send the response message  -->
    
</section>    
</div>    
</body>
<footer>
<p class="copy">Copyright (c) 2014 All Rights Reserved</p>    
</footer>    
</html>
```